# iOS - Streaming remote audio from raw data using a data task in swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm currently connecting to a **D-Link** Camera successfully through **iOS** and receiving a stream of images. I need to do the same with audio stream, however I receive raw data and have been facing difficulties in playing the data stream. Below a sample code to show the idea briefly

```
    import UIKit
    import AVKit
    import MediaPlayer

    class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDataDelegate{

        var audioBuffer = AudioBuffer()
        var audioData = NSMutableData()
        var player:AVAudioPlayer?
        var task:NSURLSessionDataTask?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            downloadImage()
        }

        func downloadImage()
        {
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://197.162.158.4:1090/audio/ACAS.cgi")!


            let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("download_session")

            let userPasswordString = "admin:admin"
            let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
            let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
            config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]

            let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            let session:NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

           task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request)
           task?.resume()

        }

        //MARK: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate

        func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData) {


            audioData.appendData(data)
            print(audioData.length)
            if audioData.length > 700000
            {

               //Need to carry out something like this
               /* player = try? AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData, fileTypeHint: AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat)
                player?.play()
                audioData = NSMutableData()*/

            }



        }

        func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {

        }

        func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didBecomeInvalidWithError error: NSError?) {

            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

Comment: Just in case you want to stream audio using some other framework -  search for "tumtumtum/StreamingKit"

Comment: Thanks @iWheelBuy, already tried it before but doesn't solve my problem since it can't handle raw data